# How to debug Jason to check which parameters made a plan not applicable?

Tags: agent, multi-agent

I have two plans in a Jason agent running in JaCaMo 0.8 platform. For some reason the first plan is being considered not applicable, so the second plan is being chosen.

My question is: How do I know which part of the expression is turning the context false?

```
// get cached Fundamentals if earlier data are younger than 30 minutes
+!opinion(T)[source(Q)] 
    : .term2string(T,S) & fundamentals::preco(S,_)[seconds_of_day(SSS)] & .time(HH,MM,SS) & (SS+MM*60+HH*60*60 - SSS < 30*60)
    & .date(YY,OO,DD) & lastDate(YYY,OOO,DDD) & YY == YYY & OO == OOO & DD == DDD 
    & fundamentals::lpa(S,_) & fundamentals::vpa(S,_) 
    <- 
    .print("Getting cached fundamentals from ",S); 
    !reply(S,Q);
    .

// get Fundamentals again
+!opinion(T)[source(Q)] : .term2string(T,S) & .date(YY,OO,DD) <- 
    .print("Getting fundamentals from ",S); 
    getFundamentals(S);
    -+lastDate(YY,OO,DD);
    !reply(S,Q);
    .
```

I have set the looging.properties file for FINE debug, part of the output for the refered agent is:

> ```
> > [greenblatt] Start new reasoning cycle [greenblatt] Selected event
> > +!opinion(ALUP11)[source(myPA)] [greenblatt] Selected intention intention 118: 
> >     +!opinion(ALUP11)[source(myPA)] <- ... .print("Getting fundamentals from ",S); getFundamentals(S); -+lastDate(YY,OO,DD);
> > !reply(S,Q) / {YY=2019, OO=2, DD=23, Q=myPA, S="ALUP11", T=ALUP11}
> > [greenblatt] Getting fundamentals from ALUP11 [greenblatt] Start new
> > reasoning cycle
> ```

I am missing some information on this log, for instante ".term2string(T,S) & fundamentals::preco(S,_)[seconds_of_day(SSS)] & .time(HH,MM,SS) & (SS+MM*60+HH*60*60 - SSS < 30*60)" was considered true? How to find out such information?

Answer (score 1):

you can store in a file the mind state of the agent for each cycle and then inspect these files to have some hint about what have failed.

In JaCaMo you can configure that log in the agent entry:

```
agent bob {
     mindinspector="file(cycle,xml,log)"
}
```

The last parameter is the name of the directory where files will be stored. Each file corresponds to a sample of the mind. They are XML files with suitable style sheets to be viewed in browsers.

Of course, this log requires quite a lot of space/time to be produced and will impact in the performance of your application.

Comment: Thanks for replying! In fact, the problem of this example is related to the parameter of !opinion which came as a prolog variable (it is being retrieved from a list that is a belief of another agent, originally a string). Anyway, what I have asked is exactly how to debug it easier.

Comment: I just realised that I can use REPL command and check whether the result of a ?(expression) is true, doing something like: ?(.term2string(T,S) & fundamentals::preco(S,_)[seconds_of_day(SSS)] & .time(HH,MM,SS) & (SS+MM*60+HH*60*60 - SSS < 30*60)
    & .date(YY,OO,DD) & lastDate(YYY,OOO,DDD) & YY == YYY & OO == OOO & DD == DDD 
    & fundamentals::lpa(S,_) & fundamentals::vpa(S,_))